# How to ignore failed request when using Promise.all?

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise

I'm building a React+Redux app, and I'm now working on a function that fetches a certain number of user's bookmarks per page.

It goes like this: when a user bookmarks a resource, the ID of the resource is stored in the database and associated with the user. So the function I'm working on fetches the IDs of the user's bookmarks, and makes API requests to fetch more info about each resource and display them to the user in a list. The API requests are all wrapped in `Promise.all()`

My problem is that if a resource bookmarked by the user was deleted, the API request obviously results in a 404 error, which causes `Promise.all()` to go into error, even though the other requests are successful. So how can I ignore the error from that single failing request and keep working with the successful ones?

Here's my function:

```
export const fetchUserBookmarks = ( bookmarkType, reset ) => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {

    if( reset ) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'RESET_BOOKMARKS'
        });
    }

    var endpoint; 

    if( bookmarkType == 'projects' ) {

        endpoint = 'posts'; 

    } else if( bookmarkType == 'images' ) {

        endpoint = 'media'; 

    } else {

        endpoint = bookmarkType; 

    }

    const bookmarksIDs = getState().currentUser.bookmarks.IDs[ bookmarkType ];  
    const bookmarksPerPage = getState().currentUser.bookmarks.perPage;  
    const start = bookmarksPerPage * getState().currentUser.bookmarks[ bookmarkType ].resultsPage;
    const end = start + bookmarksPerPage;   
    const bookmarksSet = bookmarksIDs.slice( start, end );      
    const BOOKMARKTYPE = bookmarkType.toUpperCase();    

    dispatch({
        type: 'IS_FETCHING_BOOKMARKED_' + BOOKMARKTYPE, 
    });     

    try {

        const bookmarks = [];

        const getBookmarks = await Promise.all(
            bookmarksSet.map( bookmarkID => 
                api.get( '/wp-json/wp/v2/' + endpoint + '/' + bookmarkID )              
            )
        ); 

        getBookmarks.map( request => { 
            bookmarks.push( request.data )
        });     

        dispatch({
            type: 'HAS_FETCHED_BOOKMARKED_' + BOOKMARKTYPE, 
            payload: bookmarks
        });                             

    } catch( error ) {

        if( error.response !== undefined && error.response.status == 401 ) {                

            dispatch({
                type: 'IS_EMPTY_BOOKMARKED_' + BOOKMARKTYPE 
            });

        } else {

            dispatch({
                type: 'FAILED_FETCHING_BOOKMARKED_' + BOOKMARKTYPE 
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: could you wrap each get in a promise, then in the catch, resolve with a message indicating failure?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon @nikrb's comment - you can catch all 404 errors in your requests.

Without knowing the format of the API response, the relevant code might look something like this:

```js
const getBookmarks = await Promise.all(
  bookmarksSet.map(bookmarkID =>
    api.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/' + endpoint + '/' + bookmarkID)
      .catch((error) => {
        // avoid catching unexpected errors (not due to 404)
        if (error.statusCode !== 404) {
          throw error
        }
      })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have a hack for you which I'm currently using. So what I do when I'm in the situation you mentioned, I avoid using try/catch blocks but instead build an object of the results. Lately, I'm using `redux-saga` a lot so I don't get into this situation anymore.

Anyways here's the code that I'm using

```
const buildResultObject = (promise) => {
    return promise
      .then(result => ({ success: true, result }))
      .catch(error => ({ success: false, error }));
};

Promise
  .all([p1, p2, p3].map(buildResultObject))
  .then( 
    results => {
      results.map(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          console.log(response.result);
        } else {
          console.log(`Boom: ${response.error}`);
        }
      })
    }
  );
```